# No virtual display when using modesetting in Ubuntu 20.04(xrandr: Configure crtc 3 failed)

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, xorg, intel-graphics, xrandr

I have two graphic cards in my laptop(os: Ubuntu 20.04).

```
$ lspci | grep VGA    
>> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
>> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
```

I have enabled Nvidia prime in `NVIDIA on-demand` mode. [image]

The `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file looks like this

```
section "Device"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Driver          "modesetting"
    BusID           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

And I added `20-intel.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` with following contents.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

After rebooting I ran the following commands

```
xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1920x1080
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of eDP1
```

After that I was able to create virtual display. But the graphics was [fuzzy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvSNe.jpg) & videos in vlc wouldn't play or started lagging.

After changing the driver to `modesetting` in `20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "intelgpu0"
        Driver "modesetting"
        Option "VirtualHeads" "2"
        Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

The fuzzy graphics issue was solved. But I can't create the virtual display using the above `xrandr` commands
I get the following error

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 3 failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

currently I am trying to get the VIRTUAL1 Runnung as well and I think I found your answer:
https://github.com/kbumsik/VirtScreen/issues/16

create: `sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-virtscreen.conf`
with the content:

```
`# nvidia/nouveau/amdgpu device should be configured first before Intel GPU
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidiagpu0"
    Driver     "nvidia" # Because you are using Nvidia proprietary driver. Change to "nouveau" if you are using open source nouveau driver
EndSection
# Then configure intel internal GPU
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver     "intel"
    # You may put Option "VirtualHeads" "1" here but it seem you don't need to put this for Ubuntu 18.04.
EndSection`
```

if you delete your 20-intel.conf you should be golden.
CHEERS

Comment: I've already tried this solution before posting this question here. This doesn't work for me. I get a black screen after ubuntu boots up.

Comment: I think this is because your default graficsdriver is modesetting.
I had the same issue aswell.
If you disable it, or plug in a HDMI cable and restart your displaymanager it changes to intel and nvidia and then i could use it

Comment: You can verivy this by booting without hdmi or vga plugged in, just your laptop and then enter `inxi -G`
and compare the output with when it is plugged in.

The folowing is a link to configuration with modesetting:
I haven't tried it though. You could tell me if it worked, if you tried it.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585069/unable-to-add-a-virtual-display-to-xorg/585078#585078